# Slowing process creation under Java?

Tags: java, linux, performance

I have a single, large heap (up to 240GB, though in the 20-40GB range for most of this phase of execution) JVM [1] running under Linux [2] on a server with 24 cores. We have tens of thousands of objects that have to be processed by an external executable & then load the data created by those executables back into the JVM. Each executable produces about half a megabyte of data (on disk) that when read right in, after the process finishes, is, of course, larger.

Our first implementation was to have each executable handle only a single object. This involved the spawning of twice as many executables as we had objects (since we called a shell script that called the executable). Our CPU utilization would start off high, but not necessarily 100%, and slowly worsen. As we began measuring to see what was happening we noticed that the process creation time [3] continually slows. While starting at sub-second times it would eventually grow to take a minute or more. The actual processing done by the executable usually takes less than 10 seconds.

Next we changed the executable to take a list of objects to process in an attempt to reduce the number of processes created. With batch sizes of a few hundred (~1% of our current sample size), the process creation times start out around 2 seconds & grow to around 5-6 seconds.

Basically, why is it taking so long to create these processes as execution continues?

[1] Oracle JDK 1.6.0_22
[2] Red Hat Enterprise Linux Advanced Platform 5.3, Linux kernel 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5 #1 SMP
[3] Creation of the ProcessBuilder object, redirecting the error stream, and starting it.

Comment: @oconnor0: omg... I'm having the same issue and I really start to wonder: are we both forgetting to release a resource or is there a bug somewhere?  I instantiate a **lot** of external processes and I've noticed that they get slower and slower over time. If you find your error (if any), can you please report back here?   +1 and favorited...  (btw for me this happens on OS X 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6).

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are closing the Input/OutputStreams created by the Process?

Comment: @Mike Q: in my case the external process redirect every single output to files (including stdout and stderr) so nothing is ever generated.

Comment: We're closing the input stream, but not the output stream - which we never grab. I'll do a run, in a bit, closing the output stream.

Comment: @Spoon, oconnor0:  If you create a Process object by whatever means you must close the 3 streams it creates (in/out/error) when the Process has terminated.  If you aren't doing this you are possibly leaking file handles everytime you create a process which may account for the performance degrading over time.

Comment: Do you have to close the error stream even if the error stream has been redirected to the input stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you MIGHT be running into problems with fork/exec, if Java is using the fork/exec system calls to spawn subprocesses.

Normally fork/exec is fairly efficient, because fork() does very little - all pages are copy-on-write. This stops being so true with very large processes (i.e. those with gigabytes of pages mapped) because the page tables themselves take a relatively long time to create - and of course, destroy, as you immediately call exec.

As you're using a huge amount of heap, this might be affecting you. The more pages you have mapped in, the worse it may become, which could be what's causing the progressive slowdown.

Consider either:

- Using posix_spawn, if that is NOT implemented by fork/exec in libc
- Using a single subprocess which is responsible for creating / reaping others; spawn this once and use some IPC (pipes etc) to tell it what to do.

NB: This is all speculation; you should probably do some experiments to see whether this is the case.

Comment: I'm not certain yet, but I believe you are right. I wrote a simple test program to spawn 24 programs concurrently & kept increasing the heap size & just watched the process creation time grow. I found a library at https://github.com/axiak/java_posix_spawn that I had to make some modifications to, but I'm now getting process creation times a few orders of magnitude faster even with large heaps. I'll have to see how usable that library is & if there isn't perhaps something else going on, but it would appear the answer has been found.

Comment: Did you check whether posix_spawn is implemented by fork() and exec()? Maybe it is implemented by vfork() and exec, which might avoid copying the page tables (as parent is suspended until exec)? If posix_spawn internally does the same thing, it's pointless.

Comment: Well, whatever the Oracle JDK was doing under Linux was experiencing slowing process creation & this version isn't.

Comment: It would appear that using posix_spawn instead of fork/exec fixes the problem. We're now spending very little time on process creation. I did however notice what looks like still some slight slowdown in process creation & some weirdness with processor utilization, but I can ask those in another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are running out of a resource. Are your disks getting busier as you create these processes. Do you ensure you have less processes than you have cores? (To minimise context switches)  Is your load average below 24?

If your CPU consumption is dropping you are likely to be hitting IO (disk/network) contention i.e. the processes cannot get/write data fast enough to keep them busy.  If you have 24 cores, how many disks do you have?

I would suggest you have one process per CPU (in your case I imagine 4) Give each JVM six tasks to run concurrently to use all its cores without overloading the system.

Comment: We were running with around 30 processes so I reduced that to 24 to see if that makes a difference. Including the JVM our load average is about 24.5. One of the weird things here is that we're seeing the time it takes to create each process grow.

Comment: Same as the OP: issue here is that the time it takes to create the process grows everytime.

Comment: Also when we batch the jobs per process we get full CPU utilization until the end of the run when there are no longer enough processes to use all of the processor.

Comment: How much can you reduce the number of processes to and still get near full CPU utilisation. Note: as your overhead increases, your CPU utilisation will go up but your tasks will start to take longer. The goal shouldn't be full CPU utilisation, it should be to minimise run time.

Comment: Hm, ok. I was assuming that full CPU utilization was a good thing as if there was resource contention or whatever else, there would be idle time waiting for access. At 23 external processes, I'm getting ~3% idle time & a load average of right around & sometimes over 24.

Comment: I started a run with smaller batches on a much larger object set to see what would happen & even with only 24 concurrent processes, the load average climbs to ~31 with top reporting >30% idle.

Comment: What you need to look at is how much time it takes to complete. SO try running 24 processes and time that for a smaller batch. Then time 20 and 28. find out which is lowest. then you can determine which number to try next.

Comment: Your batch size needs to be large enough that it doesn't get all it data from disk cache. i.e. larger than the amount of memory you have.  Otherwise you will find the optimal number of processes when you don't have to wait for disk.

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better off using a set of long lived processes pulling your data off of queues and sending them back that constantly forking new processes for each event, especially from the host JVM with that enormous heap.

Forking a 240GB image is not free, it consumes a large amount of virtual resources, even if only for a second. The OS doesn't know how long the new process will be aware so it must prepare itself as if the entire process will be long lived, thus it sets up the virtual clone of all 240GB before obliterating it with the exec call.

If instead you had a long lived process that you could end objects to via some queue mechanism (and there are many for both Java and C, etc.), that would relieve you of some of the pressure of the forking process.

I don't know how you are transferring the data form the JVM to the external program. But if your external program can work with stdin/stdout, then (assuming you're using unix), you could leverage inetd. Here you make a simple entry in the inetd configuration file for your process, and assign it a port. Then you open up a socket, pour the data down in to it, then read back from the socket. Inetd handles the networking details for you and your program works as simply with stdin and stdout. Mind you'll have an open socket on the network, which may or may not be secure in your deployment. But it's pretty trivial to set up even legacy code to run via a network service.

You could use a simple wrapper like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
infile=/tmp/$$.in
outfile=/tmp/$$.out

cat > $infile
/usr/local/bin/process -input $infile -output $outfile
cat $outfile
rm $infile $outfile
```

It's not the highest performing server on the planet designed to zillions of transactions, but it's sure a lot faster than forking 240GB over and over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I most agree with Peter. Your are most probably suffering from IO bottlenecks. Once you have may process the OS has to work harder too for trivial tasks hence having exponential performance penalty.

So the 'solution' could be to create 'consumer' processes, only initialise certain few; as Peter suggested one per CPU or more. Then use some form of IPC to 'transfer' these objects to the consumer processes.

Your 'consumer' processes should manage sub-process creation; the processing executable which I presume you don't have any access to, and this way you don't clutter the OS with too many executables and the 'job' will be "eventually" complete.